# Averaging over n lines, outputting to an array and then continuing

Tags: numpy, scipy, average

first time post and probably a bit easy!

I am trying to read in a large data file, where I want to read in the time-stamp from the header and then average the following 128 lines (containing numbers). Once that is done, I want to sort the data with the highest values first. I'm using numpy and scipy.

To do this, I have initially grep'd from the raw data file.

```
grep "LL" RAW.TXT > LL.TXT
```

Since I want only the 6th column, I then do this in Python:

```
DATA_LL = genfromtxt(LL.TXT,usecols = (5))
```

After this, I want to average the first 128 rows and output this value to an array. I want it to then continue to the next 128 rows and so-on until the end of the file. Outputting, perhaps, to a variable called AVERAGES.

This bit, I'm not sure how to do.

Once this array is created, I want to attach the time-stamps to the array:

```
for line in RAW.readlines():
  if line.contains("Time of record"):
    AVERAGES.append(line)
```

The only problem here is that I think it will append directly to the column, when I would prefer it to append to a new column.

After this, sort, using the normal sort command.

I think I'm on the right track, but any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One fairly straightforward way of doing this would be to track the timestamps in a separate list, then use `np.concatenate` (the [documentation on this function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) is quite helpful) with the `axis=1` keyword argument to join the timestamps array to your averages array. The biggest problem I see with this approach, however, is that as written, your `AVERAGES` variable will be appended with strings and not floats, whereas NumPy arrays are homogeneous in data type. Without some more details about the problem you are trying to solve, I don't have a concrete suggestion for how to fix this other than to use the `strptime` and `mktime` functions of Python's [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) to convert timestamps to floats.